# Sitefinty : Get Blog Category by blog ID

Tags: c#, blogs, categories, sitefinity

I want a list of all categories, which are associated with one or more blogs.
I am able to get the list of all the blogs and blog ids.
How can I get category id by blog id associated with that blog .

```
BlogsManager blogsManager = BlogsManager.GetManager();
var bb = blogsManager.GetBlogPosts()
                     .Where(b => b.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Live) 
                     .ToList();

foreach (var blogItem in bb)
{
    var blogID = blogItem.Id ;
    //get Category ID here 
}
```

Comment: Please post the definiton of a Blog

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the following using statements in your control or page:

```
using Telerik.OpenAccess;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.GenericContent.Model;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Model;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Blogs;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Taxonomies;
```

I've modified your above code to get the categories assigned to each post:

```
BlogsManager blogsManager = BlogsManager.GetManager();
var bb = blogsManager.GetBlogPosts()
                     .Where(b => b.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Live)
                     .ToList();

foreach (var blogItem in bb)
{
    var blogID = blogItem.Id;
    var categoryIds = blogItem.GetValue<TrackedList<Guid>>("Category");

    var taxonomyManager = TaxonomyManager.GetManager();

    foreach (var catId in categoryIds)
    {
        var taxon = taxonomyManager.GetTaxon(catId);

        var id = taxon.Id;
        var name = taxon.Name;

    }
}
```